# Passing array of structures to a function in different file in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, struct

I need to pass an array of structures defined in a file "file1.c" to a function, lets say "myFunc()", defined in another file "file2.c". The thing is that I don't know how to set the prototype of myFunc() in my header file "header.h" or in the function itself in my file2.c because the struct will only be defined in file1.c . Here is an example.

file1.c

```
#include "header.h"

#define dim 30
#define searchAgents 30

struct Wolf{

    double pos[dim];
    double fitness;

}Pack[searchAgents];

int main(){
    myFunc(Pack); //not sure it's ok
    return 0;
}
```

file2.c

```
#include "header.h"

void myFunc(struct Wolf Pack[]){ //I don't know how to set this argument
    Pack[0].pos[0] = 1; //just an example
}
```

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_   

void myFunc(struct Wolf); //I don't know how to set this prototype

#endif
```

I read about passing structures to functions but it's different when you have your function defined in another file. Thanks for your time.

Comment: What you did looks fine except that you should just say `void myFunc(struct Wolf Pack[]);` in header.h. Probably you want the `searchAgents` define in there as well so that you know how many wolves there are in myFunc(). (You are not passing a structure but a pointer to the first structure in the `Pack` array.)

Comment: It outputs this:    error: array type has incomplete element type

Comment: You need to insert the struct in *header.h*. File2.c doesnt know about this struct

Comment: And the function call it's ok? Because it outputs this:      error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
  myFunc(Pack);

Answer (score 1):

header.h

```
#ifndef HEADER_H_
#define HEADER_H_   

//Add all needed includes

#define dim 30
#define searchAgents 30

typedef struct Wolf{
    double pos[dim];
    double fitness;
}Pack; //Declaration

void myFunc(Pack *);

#endif
```

In main

```
#include "header.h"

int main(){
    Pack packArray[searchAgents]; //Definition or initialization if you like
    myFunc(packArray);
    return 0;
}
```

file2.c

```
#include "header.h"

void myFunc(Pack *pack){ //just a pointer to Pack structure
    pack[0].pos[0] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try making Pack[] as an extern type variable

extern keyword tells the compiler that the variable is define in some other .c file which is compiled along with this file with -o option in gcc compiler .

ex

```
extern Pack[10];
```